# Reload directive on click of $http.data

Tags: angularjs

Basically, I'm trying to create a remote file browser. When the user clicks a folder, the directive should reload with the new parameter (the path).

Please see my code below.

```
NwkApp.directive('wip', function ($parse, $http, $rootScope, $compile) {

var WipAPI = 'example.com';
if($rootScope.path === undefined) {
    $rootScope.path = new Array();
    WipAPI += "?Path="+$rootScope.path.join('/');
}


 return {
      restrict: 'E',//This makes it relevant to the Element. Other values could be A for attr, or M for comment
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: WipAPI,
      scope : {
        data: '='//binds whatever is in data, a reference to an var, obj or array.

      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {


            scope.wipBrowse = function(subpath) {

                $rootScope.path.push(subpath);


                element.parent().html('<wip></wip>');



            }//End wipBrowse

      }//End link folder
  }//End return
});
```

Basically, the template HTML contains multiple `ng-click`s which do trigger `scope.wipBrowse` once. As soon as I replace the parent html with  (in the hope I'll trigger the directive again), nothing happens.

Is there an easy way to trigger the directive to run again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure if this will help you but the click events are not firing because your html is replaced but not compiled. I made a slightly modified version of your directive:

```
app.directive('wip', function($compile, $rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E', //This makes it relevant to the Element. Other values could be A for attr, or M for comment
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'test.html',
    scope: {
      data: '=' //binds whatever is in data, a reference to an var, obj or array.

    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {


      scope.wipBrowse = function(subpath) {
        alert('alert');

        $rootScope.path.push(subpath);


        element.replaceWith($compile('<wip></wip>')(scope)[0]);



      } //End wipBrowse

    } //End link folder
  } //End return
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/OyN51DDJzFMhtM4DwJ3K?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Can you explain to me why I can't change the HTML? Why do I have to use replaceWith for it to work? Just so I know for future reference.

Comment: @Steviewevie the result of the compile function is a dom elment thus you have to use replaceWith because you are replacing a dom element with another dom element. more info about compile: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler